# Updating a preloaded data structure in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mbaas

I am building a Stock tracking/ordering/taking app on IOS with Swift.

I want to populate the database with all the items in stock and the amount there is of it manually and not from the app itself.

Then when an item is taken out of stock the amount on the pre-populated database must decrease.

Will Firebase be the best `BaaS` for my app and keep track of my stock?

Comment: Recommendations of what technology is best are off-topic on Stack Overflow. But all your requirements sounds perfectly feasible for both Firebase and likely any other mBaaS.